# Package and Deploy SSRS Reports / Datasets etc

Tags: solution-package, reporting-services, packaging

I have a VS report solution that contains around 40 reports as well as the child reports, sub reports, shared data sets, and data sources.

How do I package these for SharePoint to deploy as a managed solution? Do I just create a file deployment package (in the same way I would deploy files to the style library) or is there a specific template I should use?

Update: using SQL 2012 in SharePoint Integrated mode.

Comment: is SSRS in SharePoint mode or native SSRS mode?

Comment: Integrated Mode.